# wordpress in lan, can access wp-admin, but the website always redirected to localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost

hi i have question about wordpress.
i'm already configure siteurl and home as static lan ip.

in another lan computer i can access the admin dashboard wp-admin, `http://ipaddress/wordpress/wp-admin`

but the wordpress website always redirect to `localhost`, when i type `ipaddress/wordpress`. how can i fix this?

- I've already changed the configuration in wordpress admin in setting, general.
- I've already changed the `httpd.conf` to listen to ipaddress
- I've also tried adding lines in `wp-config.php` but still failed...

Comment: Please share more details, like your current configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wp_options table, changed the option_name= siteurl and home option_value to the your ipaddress url

Comment: done that too, still no change. i would like to add, that the http://ipaddress/wordpress and http://ipaddress/wp-admin works on the webserver pc, but on another computer in the same lan only http://ipaddress/wp-admin that works.

Comment: sorry it works, somehow the change i made in the wp-admin not recorded in the db.